# Proper files for socket.io 0.7?

Tags: socket.io

I'm developing something with node.js and socket.io, but I'm doing my local dev on Windows for my own convenience. Installation instructions for socket.io say just do `npm install socket.io`. This is fine for my linux environment, and I'm guessing node will just find it in modules. But on Windows I don't know what to do. I got version 0.6 working fine somehow, managing to find the files I need.

Now, it looks like I need two sets of files, one for the server side and one for the client. There's also two repos on github, socket.io and socket.io-client. So I'm trying to just download all the files I need from there. The issue is that the server one refers to the client one, but the socket.io-client files aren't in the server repo. If I put the server files in, and reference them in my node server, it crashes on startup saying `Cannot find module 'socket.io-client'`.

**tl;dr** If I'm just copying files into my project directory, rather than doing an npm install, what is the proper file structure to get socket.io version 0.7 running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue here and I'm not using NPM either. But nothing to do with Windows: I'm on Ubuntu with the same prob.

You also need to have the socket.io-client module available in your node_modules path or wherever you keep the server-side socket.io module.

Comment: Thanks - I got that eventually, although I don't really like how it's done that way. Then I notice I also need Redis, and that might convince me not to upgrade right now. I don't really want Redis. Why on earth would they make that dependency?

Answer (score 0):

For solving similar issues I created a runner script that simply set the NODE_PATH env variable as needed and then execute my script. I also put my own modules (or the modules I don't want to install via npm) in the node_modules subdirectory of my project. A better explanation is here http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2169-Where-Does-Node-js-And-Require-Look-For-Modules-.htm

```
#!/bin/sh

export NODE_ENV=development

if [ "${NODE_PATH}" = "" ]; then
  export NODE_PATH=$(npm -g root 2>/dev/null)
fi

node ${1}
```